# Is there any security issue when SSH log in user without home directoty?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, centos7

My system is centos 7.
My purpose is enhance server security,only let `sshuser` log in and then `su root`.

I create a user only for SSH login by `useradd -M -u 888 sshuser`.
I also set `AllowUsers sshuer` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Then when `sshuser` log in, will get notice as below:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/sshuser: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ su root
Password:
```

Is there any security issue when SSH log in user without home directoty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SSH access**

By default the ssh server looks for ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and a user without a home directory can therefor not log in with key based authentication. That implies that you currently allow password based authentication which is susceptible to brute force attacks and considered less secure.

**File access**

When users don't have home directories and they do need to store data/files they will need to find a directory they can use. By default that can only be either `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/` as no other directories are publicly available for read-write. Using such public directories may pose a risk as access there is open by design.

**`su -`**

Also when you have additional administrators you typically don't want to hand out the root password, so rather than using `su -` to gain administrator privileges,  set up `sudo` rules so that other admins can become root with `sudo -i [-u root]` and **use their personal password** rather than a **shared root password**.